# "undefined references" but it is defined

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf

Editor : Overleaf

Compiler : pdfLatex

link to the project if needed : https://fr.overleaf.com/read/jybgmhkvkzmp

**The issue :**

```
Reference `chapterfive' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.
You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled. If you have labelled it already, make sure that what is written inside \ref{...} is the same as what is written inside \label{...}.

Reference `chaptersix' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.
You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled. If you have labelled it already, make sure that what is written inside \ref{...} is the same as what is written inside \label{...}.

There were undefined references.
You have referenced something which has not yet been labelled. If you have labelled it already, make sure that what is written inside \ref{...} is the same as what is written inside \label{...}.
```

[image]

======================================

**The context :**

I have a project with the following files

```
main.tex
exercices (folder)
⮑  1.tex
⮑  22.tex
⮑  55.tex
⮑  80.tex
⮑  106.tex
⮑  136.tex
```

[image]

`main.tex` contains

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \filenumber in {1,2,...,99}{
  \IfFileExists{./exercices/\filenumber}{\input{./exercices/\filenumber}}}
  
\appendix
\chapter{chapterappendix} \label{chapterappendix}
\end{document}
```

`1.tex` contains

```
\chapter{chapterone} \label{chapterone}
\ref{chapterone}
\ref{chaptertwo}
\ref{chapterthree}
\ref{chapterfour}
\ref{chapterfive}
\ref{chaptersix}
\ref{chapterappendix}
```

`22.tex`, `55.tex`, `80.tex`, `106.tex` and `136.tex` contain

```
\chapter{chaptertwo} \label{chaptertwo}
```

just replace the "two" by three, four, five and six for `55.tex`, `80.tex`, `106.tex` and `136.tex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

106 is greater than 99 so you never input chapter 5